# Perl Scripts fails to connect to Netconf server when using Net::Netconf::Manager

Tags: perl, automation

I am using a perl script to log onto a remote router running JUNOS and get few information through the NETCONF port.
I am using the following library in order to do this

```
Net::Netconf::Manager
Net::Netconf::Device
Net::Netconf::Access
```

The script runs on the routers present on the same network but is failing to log into the routers that are on different networks, where as i am able to log onto the routers manually through Netconf over ssh.

The arguments I am parsing looks fine. Could any one help me resolve why this is happening.
If I need to do any checks in configuration (configuration looks fine to me) prior to running the script.

Comment: the code started working. when trying manually, the requests were pushed through port 22 and the default port for is Netconf is 830 which is used by the packages. The firewall was blocking port 830 and hence was not able to connect to the devices. its been fixed. Thanks